# How to get file creation or update date in js

Tags: javascript, fileinfo

How to access file information using javascript?

I'm looking for something similar to php [fileinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php) function,
applied on a **public** available css file, for example, from client side.
It would be enough to retrieve file headers with creation/update information

If it is possible, please let me know.

**Note**
Regarding some comments below, I understand that these resources are properly write protected, and made public to authorised client connections, and of course that a client cannot interfere the server OS (*in legal conditions, for sure*).
Looking for file level information, maybe embedded or available by the use of public API layers to check if the resource was modified or not (as for example, the browser cache does).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Comment: is it only for grabbing files from the client's file selection dialog, but how to retrieve that info to a file obtained using `GET`?

Comment: What are you talking about? You expecting to "browse" the users filesystem using JS directly from the browser? Thank god that it's impossible

Comment: @Alon no my friend, I'm only accessing the file infomation, to properly public set folders and resources. If that information is only about a filesystem maybe some file headers (not http of course, just for you to understand) are publicly available or the web server provides methods to get superficial file information about, properly protected resources made public to http client access by an experienced and security aware backend engineer. I hope it clarifies a little bit what I mean.

Comment: Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API) and [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) - FYI, the reason you don't see other websites allowing you to browse the files, is due to JS security limitations mking it impossible to implement. You might be able to develop internal app, it will require changing the browser settings for each client and have limited support. It won't work for normal users. Although you want to access public and basic resources on the client side via the browser, you still can't do it

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons it is not possible to access directly to client's file system using javascript. What you are trying to achieve is not permitted.

Comment: Is not present that information about file within the file structure itself?